# What is the alternative way of show message in dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, android-permissions

I want to generate a alert dialog through which a user can ***grant permission***.
But `showMessage` method has a problem in android studio.

**Error code:**

> "Cannot resolve method ' showMessage(Java.lang.String, anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)'

Are they any alternative code for doing this?

Here is the **current code:**

```
if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)){

     showMessage("bi sahab ro allow kon ",
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                  requestPermissions(new String[ 
                  {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                 REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
               }
  });
 }
```

Comment: but "showMessage" has a problem in android studio?? can you elaborate more this.

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Comment: @HemantParmar     

android studio say: "Cannot resolve method ' showMessage(Java.lang.String, anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)'

Comment: @HarounHajem
android studio say: "Cannot resolve method ' showMessage(Java.lang.String, anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)'

Comment: showmessage is not override method of android. you have to create own method.

Comment: @HemantParmar :| yes I realized the solution... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code for alert dialog. It should work.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = alertDialogBuilder
                    .setTitle("title goes here")
                    .setMessage("message goes here")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            {
                                // code body
                            }
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // code body
                        }
                    });


            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
            alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            alertDialog.show();
```

Hope this helps!!!